# SQL case when with the count result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in need of help on how to get the results, printed, partially, and not yet started. I don't know how to get the result per reference.

[SAMPLE QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONfnu.png)
[SAMPLE INSIDE THE REFERENCE. IT HAS MULTIPLE BARCODES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlgtC.png)

```
SELECT  
        REQUESTNO AS [REFERENCE NO.], 
        STATUS,
        (SELECT CASE 
                     WHEN REQUESTNO > EMP_LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS AND EMP_LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS != 0 THEN 'PARTIALLY PRINTED' 
                     WHEN REQUESTNO > EMP_LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS AND EMP_LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS = 0 THEN 'NOT YET STARTED'
                     WHEN REQUESTNO = EMP_LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS OR  EMP_LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS = REQUESTNO THEN 'PRINTED' 
                ELSE 'PRINTED'
                END As [REPRINT STATUS]
        FROM(
           SELECT 
                COUNT(REQUESTNO) AS REQUESTNO,
                (SELECT COUNT (LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS) AS LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS FROM Processing.tLabel_reprintRequestLog 
                WHERE LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS = 'PRINTED') AS EMP_LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS 
            FROM Processing.tLabel_reprintRequestLog
            ) A
        ) AS [LABEL REPRINT STATUS]
    FROM Processing.tLabel_reprintRequestLog
    WHERE STATUS In ('NEW', 'DISAPPROVED')
    GROUP by REQUESTNO, STATUS
    ORDER BY [REFERENCE NO.]
```

Comment: It would be better to share a sample of your input table and the expected output.

Comment: i attached sample photo above sir

Comment: Nothing to do with VB.NET. Please don't apply irrelevant tags.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: result should be printed, not yet started and partially printed

Answer (score 0):

There might be the need of parentheses for the condition when the condition is composed of more than one.
Basically in your example it should go like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (REQUESTNO > EMP_LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS AND EMP_LABEL_REPRINT_STATUS != 0) THEN 'PARTIALLY PRINTED'
```